# Compare Ranges to see if they are equal

Tags: vba, excel, duplicates

I am working on my computer to automate a quote in Excel with VBA
It consists of finding duplicates so they can be summed.

For example:

I have the following information:

[Click here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/oyigulk56g8xou4/Woorkbook1.xlsm?dl=0) for the Excel file

The range from A2:C4 is a group that it states there are 28 bolts, 1 nut for each bolt & 1 washer for each bolt.

A5:C7 is another group that is the same 28 bolts, 1 nut for each bolt & 1 washer for each bolt.

A11:C13 is another group but the difference is that for this one are 2 nuts & 2 washer per bolt.

So this wont be sum

This would be the result:

[image: Output Information]

I have the following code where it only looks through all the cells, I can't find a way to make it look in groups or ranges.

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim wSrc As Worksheet: Set wSrc = Sheets("Hoja1")

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

With wSrc
    LastRow = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = .Range("B1:B" & LastRow)
    LastColumn = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column + 2
    rng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytoRange:=.Cells(1, LastColumn), unique:=True
    Z = .Cells(.Rows.Count, LastColumn).End(xlUp).Row
    LastColumn = LastColumn + 1
    .Cells(1, LastColumn).Value = "Total"
    .Range(.Cells(2, LastColumn), .Cells(Z, LastColumn)).Formula = _
        "=SUMIF(" & rng.Address & "," & .Cells(2, LastColumn - 1).Address(False, False) & "," & rng.Offset(, 1).Address & ")"
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = Truek
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Click below for the Excel file

Comment: I cannot copy your screenshots into Excel to work on your problem. And I don't want to take the time to type it all in manually.  Consider pasting the data into your question as a table rather than as an image.

Comment: Thank you Ron for tacking your time to read my question.
I have attaced the file to the question.
Thanks for your advice.
I hope you can help me

Comment: In your sample, it seem the only way to separate the groups is by the fact that there are different numbers of nuts and washers.  Will that always be how groups are differentiated?

Comment: thats one and the other is if the bolt has a different diameter and/or length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that utilizes User Defined Object for the Hardware, and Hardware groups.

We could create more compact code with fewer loops, but, unless there is a significant speed issue, this is probably more readable, and can be more easily adapted to future needs.

We create two class modules (**and be sure to rename them as indicated in the code**).
One class module is for the hardware items, the second is for the different groups.

The hardware items properties are the description, the weight per item, and the number of items.

The hardware groups properties are a collection of Hardware items, and the Quantity of items in that group.

We then combine the hardware groups into a collection of unique hardware groups.

As the code is written, you could combine in other ways to generate other types of reports.

The results:

[image]

### Class Module 1

---

```
'**Rename:  cHardware**

Option Explicit
Private pDescription As String
Private pWt As Double
Private pItemCount As Long

Public Property Get Description() As String
    Description = pDescription
End Property
Public Property Let Description(Value As String)
    pDescription = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Wt() As Double
    Wt = pWt
End Property
Public Property Let Wt(Value As Double)
    pWt = Value
End Property

Public Property Get ItemCount() As Long
    ItemCount = pItemCount
End Property
Public Property Let ItemCount(Value As Long)
    pItemCount = Value
End Property
```

---

### Class Module 2

---

```
'**Rename: cHardwareGrp**

Option Explicit
Private pHW As cHardWare
Private pHWs As Collection
Private pQty As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pHWs = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Get HW() As cHardWare
    Set HW = pHW
End Property
Public Property Let HW(Value As cHardWare)
    Set pHW = Value
End Property

Public Property Get HWs() As Collection
    Set HWs = pHWs
End Property
Public Function AddHW(Value As cHardWare)
Dim I As Long, J As Long
    If pHWs.Count = 0 Then
        pHWs.Add Value
    Else 'Insert in sorted order
        For J = pHWs.Count To 1 Step -1
            If pHWs(J).Description <= Value.Description Then Exit For
        Next J
        If J = 0 Then
            pHWs.Add Value, before:=1
        Else
            pHWs.Add Value, after:=J
        End If
    End If
End Function    
Public Property Get Qty() As Long
    Qty = pQty
End Property
Public Property Let Qty(Value As Long)
    pQty = Value
End Property
```

---

### Regular Module

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub SummarizeHW()
    Dim wsRes As Worksheet, wsSrc As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim cHW As cHardWare, colHW As Collection
    Dim cHWG As cHardwareGrp, colHWG As Collection
    Dim colUniqueHWG As Collection
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long
    Dim lQTY As Long
    Dim S As String
    Dim V As Variant

    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object

'Set Source and Results Worksheets and Ranges
Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Hoja1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Hoja2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

'Get Source Data
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)) _
        .Offset(columnoffset:=-1).Resize(columnsize:=3)
End With

'Set up regex to extract number of HW items in description
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = False
    .Pattern = "^\((\d+)\)\s*"
    .MultiLine = True
End With

'Collect unique list of hardware items
' compute the weight of each single item
Set colHW = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1) 'assumes header row
    If vSrc(I, 1) <> "" Then lQTY = vSrc(I, 1)
    Set cHW = New cHardWare
    With cHW
        S = vSrc(I, 2)
        If RE.test(S) = True Then
            Set MC = RE.Execute(S)
            .ItemCount = CLng(MC(0).submatches(0))
        Else
            .ItemCount = 1
        End If
            .Wt = vSrc(I, 3) / lQTY / .ItemCount
        .Description = S
        colHW.Add cHW, .Description
    End With
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'Collect the Hardware Groups
'HW group starts if there is a "Qty" in column 1
Set colHWG = New Collection
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc, 1)
    If vSrc(I, 1) <> "" Then lQTY = vSrc(I, 1)
    Set cHWG = New cHardwareGrp

    Do
    With cHWG
        .HW = colHW(vSrc(I, 2))
        .AddHW .HW
        .Qty = lQTY
    End With
    I = I + 1
    If I > UBound(vSrc, 1) Then Exit Do
    Loop Until vSrc(I, 1) <> ""

    colHWG.Add cHWG
    I = I - 1
Next I

'Collect the unique hardware groups
' A group is defined by ALL of the hardware components being identical
' in both type and quantity.  Therefore, we can concatenate them as a key

Set colUniqueHWG = New Collection
On Error Resume Next
For I = 1 To colHWG.Count
    With colHWG(I)
        ReDim V(1 To .HWs.Count)
        For J = 1 To UBound(V)
            V(J) = .HWs(J).Description
        Next J
        S = Join(V, "|")
        colUniqueHWG.Add colHWG(I), S
        Select Case Err.Number
            Case 457 'a duplicate so add the QTY
                colUniqueHWG(S).Qty = colUniqueHWG(S).Qty + .Qty
                Err.Clear
            Case Is <> 0 'error stop
                Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
        End Select
    End With
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'Final Report
'# of columns = 3
'# of rows = sum of the number of HW items in each group + 1 for the header
J = 0
For I = 1 To colUniqueHWG.Count
    J = J + colUniqueHWG(I).HWs.Count
Next I

ReDim vRes(0 To J, 1 To 3)
'Column headers
vRes(0, 1) = "Qty"
vRes(0, 2) = "Hardware Description"
vRes(0, 3) = "Weight"

'populate the results array'
K = 1
For I = 1 To colUniqueHWG.Count
    With colUniqueHWG(I)
        For J = 1 To .HWs.Count
            If J = 1 Then vRes(K, 1) = .Qty
            vRes(K, 2) = .HWs(J).Description
            vRes(K, 3) = .Qty * .HWs(J).Wt * .HWs(J).ItemCount
            K = K + 1
        Next J
    End With
Next I

'Write the results on a new sheet
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes
    .ColumnWidth = 255
    With Rows(1)
        .Font.Bold = True
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
End Sub
```

---

Hmmm.  I see from your comments that the hardware may not always be in the same order.  I will add a sorting routine to our group generation so that will be irrelevant.

**EDIT**:  The AddHW function was modified to insert the HW items in sorted order.  Since there should only be a few items, this insertion sort should be adequate.

Comment: Thank you for your time

I Just have a question

What do you mean with "Rename: cHardwareGrp"?

Comment: When you insert a class module, it will be named something like `Class1` (just like the regular modules are named `Modulo1` and worksheets also have a default name.  You need to access the properties and change the name from `Class1` to the name stated.

Comment: It Works perfectly!! thank you, I really appreciate it.
I know that this will be too much  but how do you add a sorting routin to the group generation so that will be irrelevant the order?

Comment: @G.Hdez Since the list of hardware components will be small, I would probably sort by ensuring that the Hardware object (`cHardware`) is inserted into the collection in the group in sorted order.  That would mean modifying the `AddHW` function in the `cHardwareGrp` class module.

Comment: Ok, to be honest I don't have any Idea how to do that. I have never used clases before.

Comment: @G.Hdez For the purposes of sorting, the location of the code (Class or Regular module) is irrelevant. I'll see if I can work something out.

Comment: @G.Hdez OK, I modified that function so as to insert the HW items in sorted order.  It is a normal, ascending sort using VBA's default binary comparison.  I think this insertion sort will be fast enough since you only have a few items in each group -- but if you have 100's or more, you may want to use a different algorithm.  Also, you can probably make it a descending sort, which would return the bolts to "first place", by reversing the comparison operator in the sort, and leaving everything else the same.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a different approach.

1. take advantage of the structure; three lines define it
2. Put results on a different tab

This input ...

[image]

generates this output ...

[image]

using this code ...

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim wSrc As Worksheet: Set wSrc = Sheets("Hoja1")
Dim tmpSrc As Worksheet
Dim outRng As Range, inRng As Range
Dim iLoop As Long, jLoop As Long, QSum As Long

' turn off updating for speed
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

' setup - tmpSrc is the working and final result
Set tmpSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, wSrc)
Set inRng = wSrc.UsedRange
inRng.Copy
tmpSrc.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

With tmpSrc

    .Name = "Hoja2"
    Set outRng = .UsedRange
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns.Count

End With

' loop down through the range
For iLoop = 2 To LastRow
    If outRng.Cells(iLoop, 1) <> "" Then

        QSum = outRng.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value
        For jLoop = LastRow To iLoop + 1 Step -1 'loop up through the range to find a match

        ' matches are defined by all three rows in column B
            If outRng.Cells(jLoop, 1) <> "" And _
                outRng.Cells(iLoop, 2) = outRng.Cells(jLoop, 2) And _
                outRng.Cells(iLoop + 1, 2) = outRng.Cells(jLoop + 1, 2) And _
                outRng.Cells(iLoop + 2, 2) = outRng.Cells(jLoop + 2, 2) Then

                QSum = QSum + outRng.Cells(jLoop, 1).Value
                outRng.Rows(jLoop + 2).Delete
                outRng.Rows(jLoop + 1).Delete
                outRng.Rows(jLoop).Delete
                LastRow = LastRow - 3

            End If
        Next jLoop

        outRng.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value = QSum

    End If
Next iLoop

For iLoop = 1 To 3
    outRng.Columns(iLoop).ColumnWidth = inRng.Columns(iLoop).ColumnWidth
Next iLoop

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Edit:

- Summing weights for bolts, nuts, and washers
- Checking for case where nuts and washers appear in reverse order
- n.b. I am using .UsedRange to find the last row and last column. Other methods are available.

.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()

Dim LastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long
Dim wSrc As Worksheet: Set wSrc = Sheets("Hoja1")
Dim tmpSrc As Worksheet
Dim outRng As Range, inRng As Range
Dim iLoop As Long, jLoop As Long, QSum As Long
Dim WSum1 As Double, WSum2 As Double, WSum3 As Double

' turn off updating for speed
With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
End With

' setup - tmpSrc is the working and final result
Set tmpSrc = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(, wSrc)
Set inRng = wSrc.UsedRange
inRng.Copy
tmpSrc.Range("A1").PasteSpecial (xlPasteAll)

With tmpSrc
    .Name = "Hoja2"
    Set outRng = .UsedRange
    LastRow = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
    LastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns.Count
End With

' loop down through the range
For iLoop = 2 To LastRow
    If outRng.Cells(iLoop, 1) <> "" Then


    QSum = outRng.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value
    WSum1 = outRng.Cells(iLoop, 3).Value
    WSum2 = outRng.Cells(iLoop + 1, 3).Value
    WSum3 = outRng.Cells(iLoop + 2, 3).Value
    For jLoop = LastRow To iLoop + 1 Step -1 'loop up through the range to find a match
    ' matches are defined by all three rows in column B
        If outRng.Cells(jLoop, 1) <> "" And _
        outRng.Cells(iLoop, 2) = outRng.Cells(jLoop, 2) And _
        outRng.Cells(iLoop + 1, 2) = outRng.Cells(jLoop + 1, 2) And _
        outRng.Cells(iLoop + 2, 2) = outRng.Cells(jLoop + 2, 2) Then

            QSum = QSum + outRng.Cells(jLoop, 1).Value
            WSum1 = WSum1 + outRng.Cells(jLoop, 3).Value
            WSum2 = WSum2 + outRng.Cells(jLoop + 1, 3).Value
            WSum3 = WSum3 + outRng.Cells(jLoop + 2, 3).Value
            outRng.Rows(jLoop + 2).Delete
            outRng.Rows(jLoop + 1).Delete
            outRng.Rows(jLoop).Delete
            LastRow = LastRow - 3
        Else ' check if bolts and washers are in reverse order
            If outRng.Cells(jLoop, 1) <> "" And _
                outRng.Cells(iLoop, 2) = outRng.Cells(jLoop, 2) And _
                outRng.Cells(iLoop + 1, 2) = outRng.Cells(jLoop + 2, 2) And _
                outRng.Cells(iLoop + 2, 2) = outRng.Cells(jLoop + 1, 2) Then

                QSum = QSum + outRng.Cells(jLoop, 1).Value
                WSum1 = WSum1 + outRng.Cells(jLoop, 3).Value
                WSum2 = WSum2 + outRng.Cells(jLoop + 2, 3).Value
                WSum3 = WSum3 + outRng.Cells(jLoop + 1, 3).Value
                outRng.Rows(jLoop + 2).Delete
                outRng.Rows(jLoop + 1).Delete
                outRng.Rows(jLoop).Delete
                LastRow = LastRow - 3
            End If

        End If
    Next jLoop

    outRng.Cells(iLoop, 1).Value = QSum
    outRng.Cells(iLoop, 3).Value = WSum1
    outRng.Cells(iLoop + 1, 3).Value = WSum2
    outRng.Cells(iLoop + 2, 3).Value = WSum3

End If
Next iLoop

For iLoop = 1 To 3
    outRng.Columns(iLoop).ColumnWidth = inRng.Columns(iLoop).ColumnWidth
Next iLoop

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much!
Where can I change in the code so it can get any range, from 1 cell to the largetst range & they can be in different order the washers and nuts.

I also need to sum the weight.